JavaScript Immediately Invoked Function - Distinguishing Between JavaScript Function Expressions and Declarations
In my journey of learning JavaScript, I encountered my first practical use case for an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE).
However, I'm struggling to understand the distinction between a function declaration and an expression in this specific context.
Could someone clarify why one is considered a declaration and the other an expression?
Declaration:
function pushToColorArray() {
    // Function body
};

Expression:
(function pushToColorArray() {
    // Function body
})();


In short: because one is an expression inside  (…)(), and the other isn't.

Yes, but my question is why that is the case. It is written exactly like a declaration. I could not find any other explanation besides "yeah it is like that and this is how it is". Maybe there is some technical explanation or something else to work with?

Yes, it is written exactly with the same syntax. The only difference that distinguishes them is the syntactic context in which they occur.

I'm not sure what "reason" you are looking for. The only answer to the "why?" question would be "because the language designers thought it would be a good idea for these two constructs to behave differently".
